# Turn off Matplotlib imshow interpolation when saved as PDF

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, imshow

Is there a way to turn off the interpolation of Matplotlib's imshow function when saved as PDF?

**EDIT**

Running the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = np.random.random((200,200))
plt.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest')
plt.savefig('image.pdf')
```

will create a PDF that looks like:

[image]

Zooming in will reveal that the 'pixels' are interpolated:

[image]

Is there a way to turn the interpolation off? I am using Matplotlib 2.0.2 and Python 2.7.13.

Thanks!

Comment: That should not be the case. If in the imshow you specify `interpolation="nearest"`, the saved figure will not change this setting but  - as expected - use the same interpolation. You should in any case provide a reproducible example and in this case it would make sense to show the respective images, such that the issue becomes apparent.

Comment: How did you produce those two plots? Remember that this is a Q&A site about programming. You may also want to reread [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. [Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SMG2.png) of the pdf produced.

Comment: Thanks for checking! Which Matplotlib version do you use?

Comment: Python 2.7.10 and matplotlib 2.0.2. But possibly the issue is not matplotlib but the pdf viewer in use?

Comment: You are right! Thanks a lot for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to it by using `interpolation=None`.

Comment: Just in case. it must be without colons. "None" do not do the job.